# Cortana doesn't allow to me type more than 2 letters in searchbox and hanged in windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, cortana, cortana-invoke

Cortana opens smoothly but doesn't allow me to type **more than 2 letters** in the search box. After some time, it is hanged and Cortana disappears.

Comment: Why off-topic? There are several tags are available on this site like windows, cortana, cortana-invoking then why should it went off topic?

Answer (score 1):

I had to face this issue too, I did not get the solution even after doing lots of research on the internet, Even Microsoft Advisor told me about reinstall windows

And finally, I found an alternate solution: Classic Shell. 
you can use a classic shell. classic shell Make Windows 10 Look and Feel Like Windows 7

**Follow the steps:**

1. Go here and download classic shell - http://www.classicshell.net/
2. Install classic shell on your local computer
3. After install, select the style for start menu
4. Disable Cortana from the taskbar in Windows 10

Done, You will now feel the look of windows 7

For more details open link:- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SCnEhqmfZgc

Comment: Thanks for giving temporary solution @Udhav Sarvaiya.